# AWSの構成についての質問です。

Tags: aws, amazon-elb

現在、webサイトを3つ作成した状況で、以下の構成となっています。
【ロードバランサーA】⇨A.com(サーバーA)
【ロードバランサーB】⇨B.jp(サーバーB)
【ロードバランサーC】⇨C.work(サーバーC)

各ドメインに紐づくサーバ(EC2)はそれぞれ別のインスタンスになっています。

ロードバランサー1台あたりの維持費が高いため、以下の構成が可能か判断いただきたいです。

【ロードバランサーA】⇨A.com(サーバーA)
【ロードバランサーA】⇨B.jp(サーバーB)
【ロードバランサーA】⇨C.work(サーバーC)

独力で調べた限りですと、
【ロードバランサーA】⇨A.com(サーバーA)
【ロードバランサーA】⇨B.jp(サーバーA)
【ロードバランサーA】⇨C.work(サーバーA)
であればできそうなのですが、、、

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Application Load Balancer(ALB) で ホストベースのルーティングを行えば可能だと思います。各サーバー毎にターゲットグループを作成し、ALBでリスナー ルールで ホスト条件 とターゲットへの転送を設定します。

ターゲットグループの例：

- `targetA` : ターゲット = サーバーA
- `targetB` : ターゲット = サーバーB
- `targetC` : ターゲット = サーバーC

ルールの例：

1. IF Host header is `A.com` THEN Forward to `targetA`
2. IF Host header is `B.jp` THEN Forward to `targetB`
3. IF Host header is `C.work` THEN Forward to `targetC`

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！！
問題なくできそうですね、、、！！